# Javascript Optional chaining doesnt work with template literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to apply template literal with optional chaining.

```
type Item = {
itemId:number,
price: number};

type ItemType = {
A:Item,
B:Item
};

const data : ItemType = {
  A:{itemId:1, price:2},
  B:{itemId:2, price:3}
};

let Itemid = `data?.${variable}?.itemId`
```

where variable is a string with A or B as value.
I am not sure if optional chaining and template literals are supported together. Any Leads is appreciated.

Edited:
I am receiving "string cant be used to index type Item' when tried with `data?.[variable]?.itemId`. I have updated with type now.

Edited:
Removing type of variable helped in solving above error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wrap the variable inside `[` and `]` like: `data?.[variable]?.itemId` (it's called `Computed Property Names` and it's an `es6` feature.)

Full code:

```
let data = {
  A:{itemId:1, price:2},
  B:{itemId:2, price:3}
}

let variable = 'A'
let Itemid = data?.[variable]?.itemId
```

More:
Output of string literal is an string, so you can use `` eval(`data?.${variable}?.itemId`) `` to evaluate the value of it. (Note that using `eval` is a bad practice.)

However In your case, There is no need to use template literals. Just use `[]` as described above.

Comment: You've got a template literal within a template literal there, which won't work. I don't think there's a meaningful way to have a template literal doing what OP wanted.

Answer (score 4):

In a template the only stuff that is treated as an expression is stuff within `${}`, so in your case your optional chain indicators are part of the *string*, not part of the expression that will be interpolated into the string.

The syntax for optional chaining using objects keys is `data?.['string']?.itemId`, or if the key is stored inside a variable `data?.[variable]?.itemId`.